# Parse Server on Heroku with PFUser and Channels

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, pfuser

One of the things I liked about Parse.com was the ability to easily set up a PFUser and allow for different channels for targeting push notifications using PFCloud.  Is there a still a way to do this now that parse is shut down?

Comment: The API is still the same, so yeah. Have you tried the new dashboard + API or were you just asking beforehand ?

Comment: @nathan asking beforehand.  Did not know there was a new dashboard and API...been months since I worked with anything on parse.

Comment: It's pretty much the same except some slight variations (Localized PNs, Scheduled PNs using the user's timezone are still missing)

Comment: @nathan what is the location of the dashboard?

Comment: What do you mean ? You need to deploy your own (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server & https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard) or pay a Parse provider (there are quite a lot now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is still the same, so yeah. There are some missing functionalities like localized PNs, scheduled PNs using the user's timezone, analytics, etc.

You can deploy our own (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server & https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard) or pay a Parse provider (there are quite a lot now. Here's a list of the ones recommended by the community: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/wiki#hosting-services). Some providers offer some functionalities that others don't, you might want to check the roadmap on their sites.

Comment: Thanks.  So, I can still do like normal, set up using Heroku, and then upload the dashboard somewhere?

Comment: You can deploy both the server and dashboard to Heroku if you like. There are guides on their repos.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'll try Buddy since it is free and looks very much like Parse